# Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error in Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function

for this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#cl_submit').click(function() { //#cl_submit is a button
        $('#cl_stage1msg').html('Processing...');
        $.post("process/cookie.php", $("#cl").serialize(), function(response) { //#cl is a form
            $('#cl_stage1msg').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
</script> <!-- popup included -->
```

I just couldn't find anything wrong in this. Why is this not working, any clues?

However, `$('#cl_stage1msg').html('Processing...');` is working fine.

Seems like only the post function is not getting recognised.

I am using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js

Comment: Please include a [mcve], emphasis on *Complete*.

Comment: check your script tags, do you have a consistent set of jQuery libraries included (maybe a version or scope conflict). Could you isolate the problem, ideally as a jsfiddle?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you including?

Comment: The question is implying that this happens *only* in Chrome, and the code works in other browsers. That's unlikely the case, but you should clarify (and not talk specifically about Chrome if it's not specifically a Chrome problem.)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You are using the **slim version** of jQuery, which **doesn't include the Ajax methods** (in your case `$.post()`).

Use the **non-slim build**, available here: https://jquery.com/download/, such as:

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`

---

From [jQuery 3.0 release post](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/):

> Slim build
>
> [...] Sometimes you
> don’t need ajax, or you prefer to use one of the many standalone
> libraries that focus on ajax requests.[...] Along with the regular version of jQuery that includes the
> ajax and effects modules, we’re releasing a “slim” version [...], it excludes ajax, effects, and
> currently deprecated code.

Comment: Many thanks! I had naively copied instructions for bootstrap4, without asking myself what was `slim` about.

Comment: So how does the 'slim' version of jQuery expect us to invoke API calls?

Comment: @AsfandQazi with built-in APIs, like [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), which is jQuery's `$.ajax` implementation made with; or you can also use a library focused on AJAX, like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Comment: Instead of copy pasting you can link the solution [Ajax TypeError: $.POST is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640357/ajax-typeerror-post-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @yuriy636 Oh yeah exactly. I apologize for my downvote. I can't make any change untill you edit the post.

Answer (score 3):

If you use jquery slim version then this problem will occur. use minified or uncompressed version of jquery js file