# Ajax TypeError: $.POST is not a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax with laravel and when I clicked save button. 
I am getting this error in Console:

> TypeError: $.POST is not a function

This is piece of code:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            name = $('#name').val();
            address = $('#address').val();
            country = $('#country').val();
            $.POST("{{ route('peoples.store') }}", {name:name, address:address, country:country}, function (data) {
                $('#name').val('');
                $('#address').val('');
                $('#country').val('');
                console.log(data);
                var tr = "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+data.id+"</td>"+
                    "<td id='ename'>"+data.data.name+"</td>"+
                    "<td id='eaddress'>"+data.data.address+"</td>"+
                    "<td id='ecountry'>"+data.data.country+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+
                    "<button class='btn btn-warning' id='edit' data-id="+data.id+">Edit</button>"+
                    "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>"+
                    "</td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $('#data').append(tr);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using JQuery? If so, then the correct method is:

```
$.post();
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

I think You are using the slim version of jQuery, which doesn't have AJAX $.post function, can you try that:

`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js`