# Trying to pass data from an <a> tag, with onclick function through post() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want to deliver some data to a php page, when I'm clicking an `<a>` tag. The html is generated with jquery hence the initial file is .js.

I'm trying to use a post() method here but it doesn't work. The function(data,status)is not responding.

I apply some additional data in the `<a>`:

```
<a href="http://path" data-value = "89"></a>
```

and then I'm trying to use the post() within a click function like:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('a').click(function(){
    var num = $(this).data("value");
    $.post("products.php",{
        cat_num: num
    },function(data,status){
        $("#test_id").html(data);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: The request may not be working - check your network tab / add an error handler

Comment: well one problem is this `$("test_id")` should be either `$("#test_id")` or `$(".test_id")`

Comment: Yes thats #test_id but thats a minor issue.

Comment: Can you debug the POST request being sent either in DevTools or on the host machine?

Comment: Yes but I can't locate any error....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possible issues:

1. > The html is generated with jquery

   So, the link may not yet exist when you add the click handler.
2. You are not stopping the default behavior of the link. So, you may just be following the link before the post request fires.

Try delegating the event handler and use `preventDefault()`

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('body').on('click','a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = $(this).data("value");
    $.post("products.php",{
        cat_num: num
    },function(data,status){
        $("#test_id").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks fot the insight. I've managed to get the error. It says it doesn't recongnise the $post(). (s.post is not a function).

Comment: @EmmanuelRichman in that case do this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793829/6127393

Comment: OK thanks again. Now I'm one step closer but I get a POST http://localhost/"filepath"/products.php 404(Not Found)....

Comment: Check your routing, does that action accept method POST?

Comment: I fixed my routing and I have the right data but what is the best way to stop preventDefault() in the end of the function in order to reactivate the link?

Comment: Maybe add a class to the link `<a class="not-clicked">` use `$('body').on('click','a.not-clicked', ...` and at the end of the function remove the class. It wont be triggered again for that link.

Comment: I don't think thats what I need. That is two clicks. 1) post(), removeClass(), 2) use the <a> tag normally. I need it to be only one click.

Comment: sounds like you want a form with a hidden field (normal post request) instead, why are you using ajax?

Comment: you could just set the `window.location` to the `href` value of the link, or trigger the second click after you remove the class, `$(this).click()`

Comment: Yes this works fine. Obviously I'm a noob to all this. What I'm actually trying to do is to manipulate the content of a php page based on the <a> tag I generate with jQuery.Unfortunately and despite all your help I still don't have the required outcome so probably that was not the right way to do it the first place. Such a bummer...  Anyhow thanks alot for sharing your exp. Even if the issue is not yet resolved I manged to add a little bit more to my jQuery knowledge.

Comment: simplest way would be to use GET: `<a href="http://path?cat_num=89"></a>` then in php: `$cat_num = $_GET['cat_num'];` or `$_REQUEST['cat_num']` will access either GET or POST

Comment: @ Arleigh Hix You're a lifesaver.