# Can't send data to a php script via $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm implementing a cart on my website. It works this way: On catalog page there's four products and each has its own "Add to cart" button. Every button has its own onClick attribute which is set to addToCart() function in mu JS file. User can click on the button, and when he does so, js script is initiated. It writes product's id and increase its amount in the sessionStorage in foramt like this: "1=1", or "5=2" where the frist number is index, i.e. product's id, and second one is amount of the product.
And the next thing that I got to do is transfer info about product id and its amount to the PHP's session. And for this purpose I'm using jQuery function `post()`. But it doesn't work for some reason
add_to_cart.js:

```
function addToCart(event) {
    const PRODUCT_ON_PAGE = 4;

    event = event || window.event;
    const productId = Number(event.currentTarget.id);
    const pageId = Number(document.querySelector(".page-num-highlight").textContent);
    let index = Number((pageId - 1) * PRODUCT_ON_PAGE + productId);
    let item;
    const parseSign = "=";
    let quantity = "";
    item = sessionStorage.getItem(index);
    if (item) {
        for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            if (item[i] == parseSign) {
                for (let j = i + 1; j < item.length; j++)
                    quantity += item[j];
                quantity = Number(quantity);
                quantity++;
                quantity = String(quantity);
                
                item = index + "=" + quantity;

                sessionStorage.setItem(index, item);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        sessionStorage.setItem(index, String(index) + "=1");
    }
    
    $(() => {
        let productIndex = index;
        let productValue = quantity;

        $.post("updateSession.php", {
            index: productIndex,
            value: productValue
        });
    })
    
}
```

As you can see I process the corresponding index and value of product on which addToCart() was triggered. Index of the product is index variable, amount of product is quantity variable.

 And the next step is to send index and quantity variables to php processing script called updateSession.php in order to create/update info of product in PHP's session.

updateSession.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["index"]) && isset($_POST["value"])) {
        $index = $_POST["index"];
        $value = $_POST["value"];

        $_SESSION[$index] = $value;
    }
```

UPD1 jQuery part (unwrapped):

```
let productIndex = index;
    let productValue = quantity;

    $.post("updateSession.php", {
        index: productIndex,
        value: productValue
    });
```

UPD2:
**What is not working**: when I go to cart.php var_dump() says that $_SESSION array is empty(). And I don't know where is problem: in add_to_cart.js jQuery part or in updateSession.php

UPD3:
In my console log there's two errors when addToCart() is initiated by clicking "Add to cart" button.
These 2 errors say that post() is not a function. First says jQuery.Deferred exception and second says Uncaught TypeError

Comment: What did you expect  this syntax `$(() => { ... })` would achieve? Just unwrap the code

Comment: @mplungjan  unwrapped

Comment: So `let productIndex = index;
        let productValue = quantity;

        $.post("updateSession.php", {
            index: productIndex,
            value: productValue
        });` still does not work when you remove the wrapping?

Comment: yes it doesn't. i've updated my question, you can see how it looks now

Comment: Also please check UPD2

Comment: Hi did you put `session_start()` at top of your php page ? Also what two error are you getting ?

Comment: @Swati thank I forgot about session_start(), but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Swati yeah sorry somehow I forgot to describe errors in my question. I updated UPD3, there I describe what's wrong

Comment: Did you imported jquery cdn ? Also are you using slim version of jquery ? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793723/uncaught-typeerror-post-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @Swati yes, I did import the jQuery in catalog.php, the page which stores proudct with buttons tha initiate a js script

Comment: @Swati I am not using a slim version. Just "min.js."

Comment: @Swati I'll try to include jQuery by link tag, maybe it'll work for some reason

Comment: @Swati no it didn't

Comment: @Swati I'm a newbie in JS, and idk do I need to include jquery exactly in my js file (in this case it's add_to_cart.js). Or that's enough to just iclude jquery on the page on which JS script is invoked (in this case it's catalog.php)?

Comment: You need to include jquery in all pages where you have written jquery code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223942/discussion-between-swati-and-justlearn).

Comment: @Swati I guess I've figured out the problem. Maybe errors occur because my add_to_cart.js is located in js folder of my project. And I need to designate path a bit different way like this: $.post("./updateSession.php",). But it doesn't work as well. Maybe in JS relative paths are specified in a different way unlike HTML? Maybe I need t o specify some other sequence of "./"? Could you answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using id of object as key in JS is not a really good practice because JS reaffect key to not have lost indexes. Prefer to use full object with id key setted to your id object.

```
<button onclick="addToCart(6)">Add to cart</button>
```

In your HTML button, pass `productId` as element, it will be easier to use

```js
function addToCart(productId) {
    
    // Search if your object is already in your cart
    let cartProductIndex = yourCart.map(p=>p.id).indexOf(productId)
    
    
    if (cartProductIndex !== -1) { // If you have found it
      cart[cartProductIndex].quantity++;
    } else { // If you have not found it
    
      // Construct your object like this
      let newProduct = {
         id: productId,
         quantity: 1
      }
      
      // Then add it to your cart
      cart.push(newProduct)
    }
    
}



// Your cart will looks like this :

[
  {
    id: 3,
    quantity: 1
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    quantity: 12
  }
]


// Finally, you can send your post request

let datas = {
   cart: cart
}

$.post("updateSession.php", datas)
```

```
// Your php file

$data = json_decode($_POST['cart']);
```

So your $data variable will looks like this :

```
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 3,
        "quantity" => 1
    ],
    [
        "id" => 6,
        "quantity" => 12
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I want to use my own code. Can you point out a mistake in my code? There's three reasons why I want to use my code: 1st I've already written it and i'm 100% sure it works, 2nd is that your code seems to me too much complicated, I am newbie in JS and don't have any idea what even MAP is, and the 3rd reason is that own code is always more pleasant because you wrote it yourself :)

Comment: Ok, so like, this, I don't see important problem. But you can try few things :
- Instead of `$(() => {}` use `$(function () {}`
- Use console.log() function just before sending your post request to see if your vars exists and are not empty.
- And some times, for no some reasons still dark to me, the vars you pass in the body of your request are available as $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in your PHP code.

Comment: I've just noticed two erros in my log

Comment: But I can't attach them, because comment field here says this message is too long

Comment: But shortly saying these 2 errors say that post() is not a function. First says jQuery.Deferred exception and second says Uncaught TypeError

Comment: "And some times, for no some reasons still dark to me, the vars you pass in the body of your request are available as $_REQUEST instead of $_POST in your PHP code". You mean I can extract elements from $_REQUEST as I do it from $_POST? By doing this: $_REQUEST["index"], $_REQUEST["value"]?

Comment: Yep, but i still don't understand why. It's not necessarely the solution, but you can try ;)

Comment: It didn't help :(